# How to delimit listbox selections by comma?

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

I have a userform with a list of selections for three headings in a table. Each heading will have at least one selection. I'm trying to separate each selection with a comma and end the list with a period.

The table is populated on button click.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
    Dim tableSequence As Table
    Set tableSequence = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    Dim NewRow As Row
    Set NewRow = tableSequence.Rows.Add
    Dim MyString2 As String
    Dim MyString5 As String
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim t As String
    Dim r As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim L As Long
    Dim var
    Dim var1
    Dim MyString3 As String
    Dim MyString4 As String
    Dim var2
    Dim var3
    Dim p As String
    Dim M As Long
    Dim q As String
    Dim Y As Long
    For var3 = 0 To ListBox7.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox7.Selected(var3) = True Then
            MyString5 = MyString5 & ListBox7.List(var3)
            v = Split(MyString5, ",")
            p = ""
            For M = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
                p = p + v(M)
                If M Mod 3 = 2 Then
                    p = p + vbCr
                Else
                    p = p + ","
                End If
            Next M
            p = Left(p, Len(p) - 1)
            Debug.Print p
        End If
    Next
      
    NewRow.Cells(2).Range.Text = TextBox8.Text
   
    NewRow.Cells(3).Range.Text = TextBox9.Text
    
    NewRow.Cells(4).Range.Text = MyString2
    
    NewRow.Cells(5).Range.Text = "Engineering: " & MyString3 & "." _
      & vbCrLf & "Administrative: " _
      & MyString4 & "." & vbCrLf & "PPE: " & MyString5 & "."
    NewRow.Cells(5).Range.Bold = False
    NewRow.Cells(5).Range.Underline = False
    
    NewRow.Cells(6).Range.Text = ComboBox1.Text
    
    NewRow.Cells(7).Range.Text = ComboBox2.Text
    
    NewRow.Cells(8).Range.Text = ComboBox3.Text
    Dim keywordArr As Variant
    keywordArr = Array("Engineering:", "Administrative:", "PPE:")

    Dim keyword As Variant
    Dim myRange As Variant
    Dim startPos As Integer
    Dim endPos As Integer
    Dim length As Integer
    Dim i1 As Integer
    i1 = 1

    For Each keyword In keywordArr

        Do While InStr(1, myRange, keyword) = 0
            Set myRange = NewRow.Cells(5).Range.Paragraphs(i1).Range
            i1 = i1 + 1
        Loop
        startPos = InStr(1, myRange, keyword)
        startPos = myRange.Characters(startPos).Start
        length = Len(keyword)
        endPos = startPos + length
    
        Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range(startPos, endPos)
        With myRange.Font
            .Bold = True
            .Underline = True
        End With
    Next keyword

End Sub
```

I believe that the portion of code from `For var3` to the second `end if` should provide my comma delimiter.

The attached image shows what I'm getting on the left vs. what I'm trying to get on the right.
[image: Actual Vs Target]

Comment: I do not understand too much from your question... Do you receive such a messy list (the left part of your picture) and try splitting an element on an nonexistent comma delimiter?

Comment: `v = Split(MyString5, ",")` doesn't add commas, it splits a string that contains commas into an array, removing all the commas as it goes. I don't see anywhere in your code where you actually add any commas.

Comment: So I suppose that all that code is superfluous for my purposes. is it possible to automate inserting a comma between the selections in a multiselect listbox?

Comment: @FaneDuru well... The left part is what the form outputs to my document. I'm trying to get commas to show up between any two selections. I thought that the split function did this, but apparently I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the commas as you build the string.

```
   For var3 = 0 To ListBox7.ListCount - 1
      If ListBox7.Selected(var3) = True Then
         If MyString5 = vbNullString Then
            MyString5 = ListBox7.List(var3)
         Else
            MyString5 = MyString5 & ", " & ListBox7.List(var3)
         End If
      End If
   Next
```

Comment: Thank you! That works great! I need to  add you to my Christmas Card list or at least put you in the credits for this application lol!